# Is it possible to connect an Android tablet to Cubase 10, to use it as a MIDI instrument?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, cubase, midi-controller-drums

I am using a Windows PC. I need a way to use my tablet as a drum machine. Is it possible to connect an Android tablet to Cubase 10, to use it as a MIDI instrument?

Comment: I don't use Windows or Android, but start your search with "midi osc" & see where you get.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the sound on the Android tablet controlled by MIDI from the PC, or that you want to use the tablet as a MIDI controller (e.g. as a set of virtual drum 'pads') to control sounds on the PC?

Comment: yes, as a set of virtual drum pads to control sounds on PC.